# Adsense info not showing up in analytics

Tags: analytics, adsense

On the website [www.moviq.nl](http://www.moviq.nl) we implemented adsense. I coupled the adsenes account to our analytics account but even after a couple of days the adsense statistics are not showing up in analytics. I dropped in the code for analytics in the head section and copie/pasted the code for the adds. Is there anything else I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site isn't your primary domain you need the [AdSense Analytics code](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=94743) (which is not the same as the regular Analytics code).

Sadly, I've haven't been able to find it and have a [question about it here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568669/cannot-find-adsense-analytics-code).

As a side note, the Analytics code (if you're referring to the regular one) is supposed to be right before the `</body>` tag and not in the head section.

Comment: Ill putted the analytics code to the </body> tag. It was up there. Maybe that was the problem because the adsense code was not loaded at the moment the analytics code was loaded. I was not the original creator of the accounts but I'm prety sure it is not setup with multiple domains.

Comment: Even though it was my primary account I putted in the adsense analytics code and I moved the analytics script. Now it is working. Thanks.