# Cannot find AdSense Analytics code

Tags: google-analytics, adsense

It seems that after Analytics got their latest face-lift the AdSense / Analytics connection got a bit left behind.

According to the documentation I need to add the [AdSense Analytics code](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=94743) to my page. I already have the regular Analytics code and it's working fine. According to [Google help](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75703) the code should be in the [Edit AdSense linking settings link at the top of your account's Overview page](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=141997). But it isn't. There isn't even an Analytics Settings link in the upper corner, just Settings and that takes you to Edit User Settings.

This is how my Admin panel looks:
[image]

Has anyone been able to find it? Where is it? (It's not under Tracking Code)

Answer (score 0):

The adsense code for non-primary domains you can find in analytics. Click in adsense on link domains. Click Admin in the right corner. Click on the account. Click on data sources. Click on the adsense tab. There is the codesnippet for the secondary domain.

Comment: I don't seen any of that? Link domains, do you mean the Home / overview page? I updated my question with a screenshot of what I see when clicking Admin. ("Tracking Code" doesn't have anything about AdSense)

Comment: if you click from adsense on the go to analytics then you have one stage earlyer. There you should press admin and it brings you to an different page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue... 
here's what I found out so far:

1. in Analytics, go to Account Home (this is the list with all your domains and profiles in GA)
2. from this view, click on "Admin" in the top right corner. (This is a different admin from what you get from inside an account!)
3. select your **primary** domain/account
4. select "data sources"
5. right below the first menu with Properties, Users, Filters, Data Sources, Account Settings, there is a second menu line with 2 items: Adwords and Adsense. Select AdSense
6. you should see a list of domains you can get code snippets for

Comment: Added information:
in step 3, you should select your PRIMAIRY adsense domain, not the secundary domain that you want to add. Then follow step 4 and 5. Then you should see a list of domains from Adsense with buttons for getting the code snippets for each domain.

Comment: This takes me a step further. But at step 5, the header "Secondary AdSense domains" shows an empty table with: "There is no data for this view."
(I'll edit your answer for you)